# WPF. Отсчитать время в Async методе

Tags: c#, wpf, асинхронность

Есть WPF приложение, в котором запускается async метод. В методе есть бесконечный цикл, который что-то делает. Нужно каким то образом посчитать первые 10 секунд работы метода и вывести что-то на экран с результатом работы метода, при этом метод должен продолжать работать. Такой код:

```
private async Task WriteAsync()
{                     
    while (true)
    {
        что-то делаем...и этот результат работы на n-ой секунде передать в другое место               
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100); // ждем 100 мс и повторяем                
    }
}
```

т.е. нужен срез работы на 10 секунде.
В голову не приходит как это сделать

Comment: 1) IMHO использовать `Thread.Sleep` в асунке наверно не очень хорошо, лутше сделайте `await Task.Delay`. 2) Здача довольно общая и решить её можно по разному, может конкретизируете?

Comment: 1) На самом деле Task.Delay тоже написал, но потом закоментил..в целом наверно тоже согласен что в асунке лучше использовать Task.2) При старте программы стартует этот метод, суть заключается в том, на устройство уходит команда со скоростью 10 раз в секунду. Каждый раз приходит ответ.Нужно получить этот ответ на n-ой секунде работы метода и отобразить на главной форме.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Например, так:

```
async Task WriteAsync(IProgress<string> progress)
{
    DateTime nextReportTime = DateTime.Now + TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
    while (true)
    {
        if (DateTime.Now > nextReportTime)
        {
            progress.Report(тут ваши данные);
            nextReportTime = DateTime.Now + TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
        }
        // что-то делаем...
        await Task.Delay(100);
    }
}
```

Внешний код передаст в метод свой `Progress<T>`, и будет получать из него результаты. Вместо `string` можно, понятно, брать любой `T`.

---

Более точная версия (она прерывает паузу в 100 миллисекунд, если пришло время отчёта):

```
async Task WriteAsync(IProgress<string> progress)
{
    Task waitNextReportTime = Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
    while (true)
    {
        // что-то делаем...
        var pauseTask = Task.Delay(100);
        await Task.WhenAny(waitNextReportTime, pauseTask);
        if (waitNextReportTime.IsCompleted)
        {
            progress.Report(тут ваши данные);
            waitNextReportTime = Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
        }
        await pauseTask;
    }
}
```

---

Для случая, когда нужно выдать результат измерений лишь один раз, подойдёт такая модификация:

```
async Task WriteAsync(IProgress<string> progress)
{
    Task waitReportTime = Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
    while (true)
    {
        // что-то делаем...
        var pauseTask = Task.Delay(100);
        if (waitReportTime != null)
        {
            await Task.WhenAny(waitReportTime, pauseTask);
            if (waitReportTime.IsCompleted)
            {
                waitReportTime = null;
                progress.Report(тут ваши данные);
            }
        }
        await pauseTask;
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо. Интересно.Только не совсем понял, мне не нужно время следующего стопа (waitNextReportTime). Снять показания нужно 1 раз

Comment: @DenisIvanov: А что делать после этого? Прекращать вычисления или считать дальше?

Comment: Как и писал ранее, метод должен продолжать выполнять то что делал. 1 в 100мс отправлять запрос.... Метод основной и он главный, его не нужно останавливать

Comment: @DenisIvanov: Дополнил ответ, заодно исправил баг в предыдущей версии кода.

Answer (score 0):

Я подумал в сторону DispatcherTimer

```
int l=10; // 10 секунд;
t2 = new DispatcherTimer();
t2.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);
t2.IsEnabled = true;
t2.Tick += (o1, ee1) => { GetValuesCom(); };
private void GetValuesCom()
{

  if (l>0)
  {
    l = l - 1;
  }
  else
  {        
    t2.Stop();
    lbk.Content = ss; //ss - переменная которая фигурирует в WriteAsync
  }
}
```

Comment: А это  `lbk.Content = ss;` разве работает? И где вы вызываете `WriteAsync()` ?